# Checkout and rebase with single git command

Tags: git, git-rebase

While working with difference branches in git I usually prefer to all branches up to date with master. So my usual workflow is as follow

1. Work on the branch (e.g. feature1)
2. Checkout master and re-base branch
3. Checkout another branch (e.g. feature2)
4. Re-base (feature2) branch with master.

This way my master as wells as feature2 branch are up to date with feature 1. But I have to give two command checkout then re-base. Is there are short command for these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git rebase master feature1
```

If `<branch>` is specified, git rebase will perform an automatic git checkout  before doing anything else. Otherwise it remains on the current branch.